# Logging in django gives server error

Tags: django, logging

In my settings.py file I've added the following lines to enable logging. But unexpectedly now my project throws "500 Internal Server Error". Any ideas why ?

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
    filename=os.path.join(rootdir, 'django.log'),
    filemode='a+')
```

Comment: Not enough information... Have you checked your server logs?  My guess is you forgot to `import os` too.

Comment: Have you set `DEBUG = TRUE` in your `settings.py`? Probably you also haven't set `rootdir`?

Comment: no I didn't define rootdir. But how to set it properly ?

Comment: Does `rootdir` even exist? Doesn't seem like it. Do something like this within your settings.py: `ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` then import settings and reference the new `ROOT_DIR` in your log config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "python ./manage.py shell" and see what you get. Since it runs settings.py before giving you a prompt you should see some standard Python error messages. There are many times when Django errors are easier to debug from the command line than through a browser->server->mod_python->django chain (or whatever).